# OSGI: is BundleContext.installBundle thread-safe?

Tags: java, osgi

Can any one say if BundleContext.installBundle is thread-safe? I've read documentation, but can't find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The documentation](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) clearly states that `BundleContext` is thread safe:

> **ThreadSafe**